# Get roles and group of the user via graph - Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the names of the roles and groups that have been assigned to a user in Azure AD using the API. What API permissions are required?

I need an API for getting roles and groups. Additionally, is there any other way to access the roles and groups in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** To fetch the roles and groups that have been assigned to a user, the user or the application must have **`Directory.Read.All`** delegated API permission or Application API permission.

And make use of below query to **fetch the roles and groups**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserObjID/memberOf
```

[image]

***Output:***

```json
"value": [
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
"id": "xxx1",
"deletedDateTime": null,
"description": "Can manage all aspects of Azure AD and Microsoft services that use Azure AD identities.",
"displayName": "Global Administrator",
"roleTemplateId": "xxx"
},
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
"id": "xxxx",
"deletedDateTime": null,
"classification": null,
"createdDateTime": "2023-06-06T05:15:55Z",
"creationOptions": [
"YammerProvisioning"
],
"description": "Demo",
"displayName": "Demo",
"expirationDateTime": null,
"groupTypes": [
"Unified"
],
"isAssignableToRole": null,
"mail": "demo@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"mailEnabled": true,
"mailNickname": "demo",
"membershipRule": null,
"membershipRuleProcessingState": null,
"onPremisesDomainName": null,
"onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
"onPremisesNetBiosName": null,
"onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
"onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
"preferredDataLocation": null,
"preferredLanguage": null,
"proxyAddresses": [
"SPO:xxx",
"xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
],
"renewedDateTime": "2023-06-06T05:15:55Z",
"resourceBehaviorOptions": [
"CalendarMemberReadOnly"
],
"resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
"securityEnabled": false,
"securityIdentifier": "xxx",
"theme": null,
"visibility": "Public",
"onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
"serviceProvisioningErrors": []

}
```

**Reference:**

[List a user's direct memberships - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Note, the least privileged permissions required to read the `memberOf` endpoint is `User.Read.All` and `GroupMember.Read.All`. **Limitations:** this does not list the groups a user would become a member of if they use PIM to gain access to those groups. **See also:** [transitiveMemberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for groups, directory roles, and administrative units that the user is a member of through either direct or transitive membership.